# Access table design - two options - which is better?

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access-2007

I have a table I need to store sample analysis data from a lab for different products.  I have two options.  I would normally use option #1, but am wondering if I should start using a version of option #2.  For each sample, even of the same product, I request different tests each week, but some are duplicated, some are not.  Below are the options I could use...

Option #1

```
 SampleID     pH      Solids        Calcium        Nitrogen
 3755        4.2       20.6           15.8
 3756        4.35                     15.7           12.2
```

Option #2

```
 SampleID     TestID     TestValue
 3755           1         4.2
 3755           2         20.6
 3755           3         15.8
 3756           1         4.35
 3756           3         15.7
 3756           4         12.2
```

TestID would link to a table that would have the testID numbers and the test names.  Option #2 would have no empty field values ever, but more rows.  Option #1 would have lots of empty values, but all values for each sample would be together in a row.  As I understand a database more, I think Option #2 is what they are all about.  One last thing to note, While I have four tests in my above example, it would really be 50+.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, option #2 is more normalized. And adding other tests later would be easy.
Plus, if you have 50+ tests, the application design will be easier.

Btw, I would be tempted to use a TestCode instead of TestID. The code would be a 2-3 letter representation of the test. It will take up a little more space & CPU, but really both would be negligible. And it would be easier to read if you ever had to look at the table directly.

Comment: I suspect that even the full test name would not hurt, judging by the sample. It would be easy enough to keep a table of tests for integrity.

Comment: The TestID vs TestCode or TestName doesn't really bother me.  I have been averaging 1100 samples/week, with some having 1 test, while others have 12 tests, or more.  One follow up question:  What if I have 5 tests that EVERYTHING gets?  Do I still use option 2, or a table like option 1 for the 5 and table like option 2 for any additional tests...?

Comment: I think you should stick to option 2, it is by no means difficult to create code or a query to append the standard tests.

Comment: I agree, it is not difficult.  I like the consistency of only using one table.  Thanks for all the help!